# message sent to deallocated instance ,,, [__NSArrayI respondsToSelector:]

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have this implementation file with a`NSArray` object userIDs

```
NSArray *userIDs;
NSInteger friendID;

@implementation TableViewController

-(void)reciveFriendsIDs:(NSArray *)array
 {
userIDs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
 }

-(NSString *)getFriendId
{
 return [userIDs objectAtIndex:friendID];
}
.
.
.
@end
```

and the method `-(NSString *)getFriendId` call it from another class like this :

```
TableViewController *tableController = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
NSString *fid = [tableController getFriendId];
```

But I am having an error said "-[__NSArrayI respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x20320200" and the compiler indicate the error in this line:

```
return [userIDs objectAtIndex:friendID];
```

Comment: Is userIDs retained ? Where do you allocate it ?

Comment: I update the post ,,, take a look
the method reciveFriendsIDs get called before getFriendId so the userIDs will be allocated I think

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are allocating the NSArray with arrayWithArray static method.

In this way it's getting added in the auto release pool and the retain count will be 0.
Either retain it or manually alloc it with [[NSArray alloc] init]

Comment: if I use the [[NSArray alloc] init] way is this right ? 
userIDs = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array] autorelease];

Comment: THANK YOU! for anyone else (like me) having extreme difficulty finding a solution...avoiding the arrayWithArray method was what finally did it for me

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception on line

```
 if(self.arrTypes != nil)
```

cause of the following line being used at a different place in code

```
 [self.arrTypes release];
```

and replacing this code with

```
 self.arrTypes = nil;
```

resolved the issue.